# Hexadecimal Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, hex

I'm writing a small code using `serialport` module of node js

Docs of my hardware chip specified my tranmsitted data to be a byte array of hexadecimal numbers.

However, I have the values stored in decimal notation.
Using `myDecimalnumber.toString(16)` returns in hexa notation but in string format. I need in `Number` format. Converting the resultant into number is making it decimal again, but not in hexa!

I'm confused as to how to send the data to the chip. Please suggest!

Comment: you may have a look to the [indexed collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects#Indexed_collections)

Answer (score 2):

Numbers are just numbers, they don't have a number base.

> However, I have the values stored in decimal notation.

No, you don't. The only way it could be in decimal notation would be if it were a string, but if `myDecimalnumber.toString(16)` gives you a hex string, then `myDecimalnumber` is a `Number`, not a string (or you have a custom `String.prototype.toString` method, but I'm sure you don't).

> Using `myDecimalnumber.toString(16)` returns in hexa notation but in string format. I need in `Number` format.

A number has no concept of a number base. That's a concept related to the *representation* of a number. That is, `10` decimal is `12` octal is `A` hex. They're all the same number. It's just their representation (e.g., how we write it down, its string form) that involves a number base.

> Docs of my hardware chip specified my tranmsitted data to be a byte array of hexadecimal numbers.

That seems really unlikely. If it's the case, it was written by a hyper-junior engineer or mistranslated from another language.

The chip probably requires an array of integers (numbers), but you'll need to refer to the documentation to see what size of integeres (8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, etc.). But it *could* be that it requires an array of characters with data encoded as hex. In that case, you need to know how many digits per number it requires (likely values are 2, 4, etc.).

But again, fundamentally, number bases are only related to the *representation* of numbers (the way we write them down, or keep them in strings), not actual numbers. Numbers are just numbers, they don't have a number base.